# GCE windows server without built in SQL server

Tags: google-compute-engine

We create a windows GCE server from the google image (without SQL server).
Can we install the SQL server (with our on-prem license with software assurance) to this GCE server? or we have to create our own image and create the server from it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have License Mobility as part of Software Assurance, you can assign a SQL Server license to virtual machines running on multi-tenant hosts or on sole-tenant nodes.

Verify your benefits at the Microsoft [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/licensing-programs/software-assurance-default).

[Google Cloud SQL Server FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/ms-licensing-faq#sql-server)

Comment: Is that mean I can still use the Google public image to create the windows server (without SQL server) instead of using my own windows server image?

Comment: @PJS - I believe you can. However, you need to read your license agreement for the terms you are eligible for. Your Software Assurance agreement is not the same as mine (or another customer).